# Error while converting absolute path to relative path

Tags: javascript, excel, relative-path, absolute-path

I am using a javascript code which needs to open a csv file but I get the error as "**ThisWorkbook is undefined**". Not really sure what is the error. Kindly help !

```
var xl = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    xl.Visible = true;
    var wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\\" & "temp.csv");
    var sheet = wb.ActiveSheet;
    wb.Worksheets.Add(after=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count));
    var pws = wb.ActiveSheet;
    pws.Name="temp_pivot";
    var pvtTable = pws.PivotTableWizard(1, varSource=wb.sheets("temp").Range("A1").CurrentRegion);
    pvtTable.PivotFields("DECISIONYEAR").Orientation = 1;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("DECISIONMONTH").Orientation = 1;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("APPLICANT").Orientation = 4;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPLICANT").Function=-4157;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPLICANT").Caption="Applicants";
    pvtTable.PivotFields("APPROVED").Orientation = 4;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPROVED").Function=-4157;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUM OF APPROVED").Caption="NAA";
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SOURCE").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("PRODUCTCOLOR").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("PRODUCT").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("SUB_CHANNEL_CADM").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("CHANNEL_CADM").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("MARKET").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.PivotFields("OFFER_TYPE").Orientation = 3;
    pvtTable.DataPivotField.Orientation=2;
    pws.Columns.Autofit;
    pws.Rows.Autofit;
    xl.DisplayAlerts =0;
    xl.DisplayAlerts = 1
    xl.CutCopyMode = 0;
    xl.EnableEvents = 0;
    xl = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

`\"` is seen as an escaped quote in a string literal. This means your `"\"` string isn't closed.

Replace

```
"\" & "temp.csv"
```

with

```
"\\" & "temp.csv"
```

Using a proper code editor, the colors of the code would have been an hint of where the problem was (as in this answer).

Answer (score 0):

Replace: `"\"` with `"\\"`

In `"\"`, the slash escapes the 2nd quotemark, meaning your string won't be terminated there.

To have a string contain a backslash, you'll have to escape that backslash (`"\\"`), so the compiler / interpreter doesn't try to interpret it as an escape character.

Comment: okay ! so I did the change but now I get the error as ThisWorkbook is undefined

Comment: @user3444944: Where did you (attempt to?) set `ThisWorkbook`?

Comment: I have not set ThisWorkbook. How should I do that. Kindly enlighten me.

Comment: @user3444944: what is `ThisWorkbook` supposed to be?

Comment: Even I'm a newbie and googled for that. Few links suggested me to use ThisWorkbook which I've used. My requirement was just to use a relative path instead of fixed one as described in the third line.

Comment: Looks like you may need to use something like `Application.ThisWorkBook`.